# Каким образом данные преобразовать в строку?

Tags: php

Есть код, который разбивает массив, и проставляет запятые между значениями, кроме последнего значения.

Каким образом все это полученное значение преобразовать в одну строку, и использовать вне цикла?

```
$i = count($specz);
$s = 0;

foreach ($specz as $word) {
   $s++;
   echo $word;
   if ($i != $s)echo ",";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

```
<?php

    $array = ['lastname', 'email', 'phone'];
    $comma_separated = implode(",", $array);
    echo $comma_separated; // lastname,email,phone

    $stop_separated = implode(".", $array);
    echo $comma_separated; // lastname.email.phone

    $stopnspace_separated = implode(". ", $array);
    echo $comma_separated; // lastname. email. phone
```

**цикл не нужен** Ваш код будет:

```
<?php

    $specz = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"];

    $stringSpecz = implode(",", $specz);
```

Comment: точно, спасибо!

Comment: но разбивать массив мне не нужно, мне нужно получить его значения, и отобразить на экран, вне цикла

Comment: то есть, в цикле получаем значения: 1,2,3 . а вне цикла, нужно вывести все это одной строкой

Comment: @Денис `implode` - не разбивает а склеивает. Вы с `explode` перепутали.

Comment: точно. все, понял теперь. спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @Денис Если ответ правильный пометьте как принятый